# htmlentities() makes Chinese characters unusable

Tags: php, html-entities

we have a web application where we allow users to enter their own html in a text area. We save that data to our database.

When we load the html data into the text area, of course, we use htmlentities() before throwing the html data into the textarea. Otherwise users could save  inside the textarea and our application would break when loading that into the textarea.

this works great, except when entering Chinese characters (and probably other languages such as Arabic, Japanese).

The htmlentities() makes the chinese text unusable like this: Ã�Â¨Ã�Â³Ã�Â¼Ã�Â§Ã¯
When I remove the htmlentities() before loading the entered html into the text area, Chinese characters show up just fine, but then we have the problem of HTML interfering with our textarea, especially when a users enters  inside the text area.

I hope that makes sense.

Does anyone know how we can safely and correctly allow languages such as Chinese, Japanese, ... to be used inside our text area, while still being safe for loading any html inside our text area?

Comment: Try specifying `charset` parameter

Comment: What character encoding are you using?

Comment: What character set is defined for your page?

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars` if you just want to replace the HTML special characters.

Comment: passing in the character encoding as a parameter helped, just like using htmlspecialchars, thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

I currently use that in production and it's fine.

```
$foo = "我的名字叫萨沙"
echo '<textarea>' . htmlspecialchars($foo) . '</textarea>';
```

Alternately,

```
$str = “&#20320;&#22909;”;
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, ‘UTF-8′, ‘HTML-ENTITIES’);
```

As found on http://www.techiecorner.com/129/php-how-to-convert-iso-character-htmlentities-to-utf-8/

Answer (score 2):

Specify charset, e.g. UTF-8 and it should work.

```
echo htmlentities($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: this works as well, but we already found our answer above. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

PHP is pretty appalling in terms of framework-wide support for international character sets (although it's slowly getting better, especially in PHP5, but you don't specify which version you're using). There are a few `mb_` (multibyte, as in multibyte characters) functions to help you out, though.

This example may help you (from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)):

```
<?php 
/** 
 *  Multibyte equivalent for htmlentities() [lite version :)] 
 * 
 * @param string $str 
 * @param string $encoding 
 * @return string 
 **/ 
function mb_htmlentities($str, $encoding = 'utf-8') { 
    mb_regex_encoding($encoding); 
    $pattern = array('<', '>', '"', '\''); 
    $replacement = array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&#39;'); 
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($pattern); $i++) { 
        $str = mb_ereg_replace($pattern[$i], $replacement[$i], $str); 
    } 
    return $str; 
} 
?>
```

Also, make sure your page is specifying the same character set. You can do this with a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not using the correct encoding. If you already know your output encoding, use the `charset` argument of the [`html_entities` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

If you haven't settled on an internal encoding yet, take a look at the [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php) functions; `iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");` might be a good start.